# open link in new tab after click

Tags: javascript

I opened a new  window by window.open in JavaScript, the probleme that it work just after refresh

```
    var url=document.getElementById("largeImage").getAttribute("href");

   $("#largeImage").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();
   var win=window.open(url);



  });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript

Comment: If possible your first preference should be to use anchor tag in html for this purpose `<a href='someurl.html' target = '_blank'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just add an anchor around your image and open a new tab by using the href-attribute?

Example:

```
<a href="url"  target="_blank" >
<img />
</a>
```

Comment: It's not correct either actually, edit your answer so that it reads `<a hre"/url-path" target="_ blank">`

Comment: it's opened but the probleme is it not work , i have to refresh the page  to work

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1, JavaScript approach

This will work

```
function openInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
<div onclick="openInNewTab('www.test.com');">Something To Click On</div>
```

Reference, and more info, here: http://www.tutsplanet.com/open-url-new-tab-using-javascript-196/

### Option 2, HTML approach

Really simple, just use the `target='_blank'` to your anchor link, e.g:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://your_url_here.html">Link</a>
```